# Why is this exception not found with breakpoint "when exception thrown"

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator, msvc12

In my Qt application (VC12, Qt Creator, Qt 5.3) I see an issue when I close my application:

[image: exception issue]

As I have no idea why (where caused?, my fault?) I have tried to find the root cause. I have used the breakpoint types ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553842/breakpoint-break-when-c-exception-is-thrown-why-so-slow))

- Break when C++ exception is thrown
- Break when C++ exception is caught

[image: Breakpoint type]

However, these breakpoints are never hit (or, at least the application never stops at such a breakpoint). I wonder:

How can it be, that I see an exception issue, but being unable to detect it with one of the breakpoints above?

Comment: Because that is not a C++ exception.

Comment: Ok, it is what? So what does it mean, how do I handle it?